# How to solve the quadratic matrix equation $A = BC B^H$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, quadratics, matrix-equations

Given $6 \times 6$ matrix $A$ and $2 \times 2$ matrix $C$, 
I would like to solve the following quadratic matrix equation in $6 \times 2$ matrix $B$

$$A = BC B^H$$

How to find the matrix $B$?  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Tells us more. Are $A$ and $C$ symmetric? Positive definite? Is $C$ invertible?

Comment: This is straightforward if $A$ and $C$ are Hermitian.  I'm not sure how to approach the question more generally, though.

Comment: A is not symmetric. C is a diagonal matrix and symmetric. @RodrigodeAzevedo

Comment: If $C$ is symmetric, then $A$ must be Hermitian! Take the Hermitian transpose of both sides of the matrix equation.

Comment: @Srivally.M, take the Hermitian does not change the size of the RHS. It is not magic!

Comment: @AlexSilva yes, size of RHS is not changing, but how to find B after taking hermitian on both sides.

Answer (score 1):

You should be more specific about your matrices $A$ and $C$, otherwise the problem may not have a solution. For instance, consider the following matrices:

$$A = \begin{matrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
          -1 & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{16}\\
          a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{26} \\
          \vdots &  \vdots &  \ddots &  \vdots \\
          a_{61} & a_{62} & \cdots & a_{66}\\
          \end{bmatrix}\\
    \end{matrix}~\text{and}~~ C = \begin{matrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
          1 & 0\\
          0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}\\
    \end{matrix}.$$

Applying the $\text{vec}$ operator on $A = BCB^{H}$ we have,

$$\text{vec}(A) = \text{vec}(BCB^{H}) = (B^{*}\otimes B)\text{vec}(C).$$

$B^{*}\otimes B$ is a $36 \times 4$ matrix whose first element is $|b_{11}|^2$. Hence, we would have

$$|b_{11}|^2 = -1,$$
which does not provide any solution.

Comment: thank you. A is symmetric matrix and C is diagonal matrix and symmetric. How to find B in matrix form without using vec.

Comment: @Srivally.M, Even if the matrix $A$ in my example is symmetric (e.g., just set $a_{ij} = 0$ for $i\neq 1$ and $j\neq 1$) the problem has still no solution. Again, you should be more specific about your entries $A$ and $C$. For instance, if $C$ is invertible, the problem becomes more interesting. There is no particular method for solving the general case.